langchain DirectoryLoader stuck when reading .md files
Trying to create embeddings from .md files but DirectoryLoader is stuck. This works for pdf files but not for .md.
I am using the below code to create a vector db in chroma, this works perfectly when using the commented loader to read pdfs but when using the current uncommented line to read .md files it just stops
this is inside a method in a class
# loader = DirectoryLoader(self.data_directory+'/', glob="./*.pdf", loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
loader = DirectoryLoader(self.data_directory+'/', glob="./*.md",loader_cls=UnstructuredMarkdownLoader)
print("loader")
documents = loader.load()
print("loaded? ")
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
print("split? ")
vectordb = Chroma.from_documents(documents=texts, 
                                        embedding=self.embedding,
                                        persist_directory=self.persist_directory)
print("persisted? ")

retriever = vectordb.as_retriever()
return retriever

the last thing that is printed is "loader" and "loaded?" is not printed. any obvious problem i am missing?
loader
      0 [main] python (11932) c:\python312\python.exe: *** fatal error - Internal error: TP_NUM_C_BUFS too small: 50
    315 [main] python (11932) c:\python312\python.exe: *** fatal error - Internal error: TP_NUM_C_BUFS too small: 50

The above output sometime appears when I try to load the .md file. no idea what this is.

Installing the below solved it somehow
     pip install python-magic python-magic-bin

found the solution here : some other question

To load markdown documents, use UnstructuredMarkdownLoader function, as below example
markdown_path = "../README.md"
loader = UnstructuredMarkdownLoader(markdown_path)

Documentation reference > https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/modules/data_connection/document_loaders/markdown/

This only loads individual files, UnstructuredMarkdownLoader cannot do the same as DirectoryLoader. With this usecase you need to load many, many files
